# Privacy policy URL in Facebook login

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I need to provide Facebook log in for my website. I registered the application in Facebook. While sending for review they are asking a privacy policy URL. Can any one explain in detail what is that and what should i enter in it?

Answer (score 1):

The privacy URL is a part of the **App Details** section that is <strike>required only if you submit you app to the App Center.</strike>

<strike>If you dont want to submit your app to app center (which is not required), you can avoid submitting the App Details for review.</strike>

**Edit:** (@WizKid, thanks for the correction)

Even if you dont want your app in the App Center, facebook asks for a privacy url (a url listing the provacy policy for your app/company); and they will **disable** your app if you don't provide one when asked!

Comment: You need one even if you are not in App Center. We will disable your app it you don't

Answer (score 1):

You need to set privacy policy URL (https://www.xxxxx.com/privacy-policy/) which will include different meta tags in the head of its source code :

meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxx"

meta property="og:type" content="article"

meta property="og:title" content="Introducing our New Site"

meta property="og:image" content="https://www.xxxxxx.co/xxxx.png"

meta property="og:description" content="xxxxxxx"

After that, check your URL on facebook debugger that it is correct or not.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=

Then go to your facebook developer console and check. If it still persists then try again after removing the platform.